# from 1000 to 2000 php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, random

I'm trying to run a mysql query which selects all users from a table where the rank is from 5000 to 15000. Those two have been put into variables. Let me change this into code, it'll explain it better.

```
$user_rank = 10000 //this is actually a $row[''] pulled from a database
$rank_above = $user_rank + 5000;
$rank_below = $user_rank - 5000;

$fetch_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE rank = '$rank_below' ?to? '$rank_above'");
```

However, I also want to make the result a LIMIT 1 random result, so that it only selects one random user from the users table. Am I even going about this the right way?
Any help much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Don't use string interpolation to build your SQL strings. For that matter, don't use the `mysql` module. Ever. Including legacy code.  (Use `mysqli` module instead, at the very least.)

Comment: Yeah I keep seeing that, is it just old and dated or are there security issues and cross browser missfunctioning?

Comment: Security issues. String concatenation / interpolation is THE easiest way to end up with SQL injection holes. The **best** way to avoid them is using prepared queries and parameter substitution, which `mysql` simply does not have at all. (While `mysqli` does, using [`mysqli_bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).) You can avoid SQL injection when using `mysql` using `mysql_real_escape_string`, but IMO it's easier to remember to apply parameter binding consistently, than it is to remember to wrap all user input with that function. (The latter also looks hideous.)

Comment: As a bonus parameter binding also takes care of quoting strings (or not quoting non-string parameters) for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) clause in mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE rank BETWEEN  5000 AND 15000"
```

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE rank BETWEEN %d AND %d"
$sql = sprintf($sql,(int)$rank_above,(int)$rank_below); // sanitize user input
```

Comment: I assume this works with vars? BETWEEN '$upvar' AND '$downvar' assuming the vars have the string of ints in them?

Comment: Does one of you know if that is more performant than `WHERE rank >= 5000 AND rank <= 15000`? Just wondering...

Comment: @VVV please keep in mind, that the MySQL operator BETWEEN .. AND ... is equivalent to expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max).  This is important to know, in case you need something like (min <= expr AND expr < max).

Comment: @pebbo It is extremely unlikely the two are evaluated any differently bu a SQL engine. With the exception that if you do `when X<Y and Y<Z`, the expression `Y` is probably evaluated twice; with `when Y between X and Z` I'd expect `Y` to only be evaluated once. (Assuming `Y` is a computed expression of some sort.)

Comment: Hmm, expression being the variable? I'm having a bit of trouble adding another AND clause to ma sure the user_logged_in isn't selected at random.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE rank BETWEEN $rank_below AND $rank_above
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Ah, I guess you can't ask for more exact than that !